# Badtokenexception androidx

Tags: android, exception, toast

Started getting a BadTokenException on Android 7.1 since shifting to androidx. Its supposed to be a known bug in 7.1 for Toast [link](https://github.com/drakeet/ToastCompat) but I am not so sure because it only started shortly after I shifted to androidx.

Checked my git history and I have not touched any of the Toast code before shifting to androidx. I also didnt have exceptions on 7.1 before.

Obviously I cant reproduce it and stack trace doesn't have any of my code reference. The exceptions are accumulating and I need help in fixing this.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:689)

  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)

  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:94)

  at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow (Toast.java:511)

  at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage (Toast.java:385)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6228)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 1):

Type TOAST not allow to add view in android 7.1.1, 7.1.2 using

WindowManager.LayoutParams

You can use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT instead and using alert permission in Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```